# Нужно посчитать количество чисел, которые больше или меньше заданного

Tags: python

Нужно посчитать количество чисел, которые больше или меньше заданного в списке. Пользователь, соответственно, сам вводит число. Я начала - но как дальше не знаю.

```
 nomer = input('Введите число: ')
    sch = input('Считать числа больше заданого или меньше? ')
    if not (sch == 'больше' or sch == 'меньше'):
```

Comment: Больше прям до бесконечности?

Comment: нет, в разумных пределах,  на 30-50

Comment: Пересмотрите еще раз условие задания, количество чисел посчитать можно между двумя заданными.

Comment: Пусть даны числа _a_ и _b_, тогда между ними _b - a - 1_ чисел

Comment: "Порахувати кількість чисел більших (менших) за вказане число у одновимірному числовому масиві. Користувач сам вводить число і вказує які числа рахувати."

Comment: Перебирайте числа в списке и сравнивайте с заданным.

Comment: Можете пж подсказать как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть дан массив (список) чисел. По нему надо пройтись с помощью цикла `for`,проверить условием число (элемент массива) больше (меньше) заданного и при выполнении условия увеличить счетчик:

```py
nomer = int(input()) # Ввод числа с которым сравниваем элементы массива
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0] # Массив в котором производим подсчет
more_less = input('Введите какие числа считать (more/less):') # Ввод параметра по которому будет производиться сравнение
cnt = 0 # Создание счетчика
if more_less == 'more': # Проверка значения переменной more_less, если значение more
    for i in lst:
        if i> nomer:    # ищем элементы массива больше заданного
            cnt+=1      # при верном условии увеличиваем счетчик
else:                   # иначе, если значение more_less равно less
    for i in lst:
        if i< nomer:    # ищем элементы массива меньше заданного
            cnt+=1      # при верном условии увеличиваем счетчик
print(cnt)              # выводим значение счетчика на экран
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: как сделать что бы оно просило ввести считать больше или меньше?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить переменную `more_less` принимающую значения _more_ или _less_ (`more_less = input('Введите какие числа считать (more/less):')`). Затем программу разветвите условием `if more_less == 'more': ... else: ...` вместо троеточия подставьте циклы, с соответствующей проверкой элементов.

Comment: more_less = input('Введите какие числа считать (more/less):'))
if more_less == 'more': else 'less' 

так?

Comment: Обратите внимание на текст программы в ответе. Там код уже с учетом выбора какие числа подсчитывать.

Comment: я не понимаю как выглядит полный текст программы вместе с  тем что бы спрашивало как считать

Comment: все, разобралась

Comment: выводит ноль почему-то

Comment: Введено число за пределами массива, проверяете числа больше (меньше), чем в массиве. Можно создать рандомный  список (как сделать посмотрите в ответе у @rokitoker)

Comment: огромное спасибо!!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

Range соответсвенно можно задать любой, как и число. А это так, для примера.

```
   array = [i for i in range(10,21)]
   num = 5
   more = 0
   less = 0
   for i in array:
          if i < num: less += 1
          if i > num: more += 1
```

Comment: ничего не происходит когда ввожу код(

Comment: ну если нужно вывести числа, то print(less,more)